# How do gems built for java work? Getting error install torquebox gem

Tags: rubygems, jruby, torquebox

I'm clearly missing something here. I'm trying to install the torquebox gems and am running into this error (on a mac):

```
gem install torquebox-server --pre --source http://torquebox.org/2x/builds/LATEST/gem-repo/    

Could not find a valid gem 'torquebox-server' (>= 0), here is why:
          Found torquebox-server (2.x.incremental.424), but was for platform java
```

I have jruby installed, version 1.6.3. It's in my path. I don't understand the above error. If you need any more info let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marc:

It looks like it is using the MRI version of gem. If JRuby is in your path, try:

```
jruby -S gem install torquebox-server --pre --source http://torquebox.org/2x/builds/LATEST/gem-repo/
```

You may also need to run the torquebox command via JRuby explicitly as well:

```
jruby -S torquebox deploy .
jruby -S torquebox run
```

Also, you should upgrade to JRuby 1.6.4 if possible - it fixes a few issues that we encountered in 1.6.3, and is what we currently test TorqueBox with.

Comment: Ok great works. And if I wanted to try out torquebox 1.1 and use it with rails, how do I make sure bundle install works? If I simply put gem "torquebox" in my gemfile it doesn't seem to know to use jruby. Or for that matter putting the torquebox 2.0 gem in my gemfile.

Comment: Ah, figured it out. With the rails bundler you can add to your gemfile :jruby do xxx. Thanks!